# How to dynamically add amount of times same input has been entered into textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have only recently started with Javascript and been stuck on  this problem that seems rather easy but breaking my head on it.

I am trying to basically ask people for their name for a not specified amount of time and instantly add and show it as a LI under the textbox. But I can not figure out how to make it so that someone enters Pablo but Pablo has been entered already it will make it like this Pablo: 2 or 3 if more get entered..

Jsfiddle here -->  https://jsfiddle.net/uw1qeg7y/1/

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <script src="AantalVoornamen.js" defer></script>
    <title>Voornamen</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="javascript.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
    <label>Voornaam: <input id="voornaam" autofocus></label>
    <button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen</button>
    <ul id="voornamen">
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

JS CODE

```
"use strict";

document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function () { 
const voornaamInput = document.getElementById("voornaam"); 
const voornaam = voornaamInput.value; 
const li = document.createElement("li"); 
li.innerText = voornaam; 
document.getElementById("voornamen").appendChild(li); 
voornaamInput.value = ""; 
voornaamInput.focus(); 
};
```

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the list in a variable and keep pushing the names into that array before adding `li` in the Dom. Also before adding we can also check whether the `name` is being added already or not.

```js
let namesList = [];

document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function () { 
   const voornaamInput = document.getElementById("voornaam"); 
   const voornaam = voornaamInput.value; 
   if(!namesList.includes(voornaam)) {
     const li = document.createElement("li"); 
     li.innerText = voornaam; 
     namesList.push(voornaam);
     document.getElementById("voornamen").appendChild(li); 
     voornaamInput.value = ""; 
     voornaamInput.focus(); 
   }
};
```

```html
<body>
   <label>Voornaam: <input id="voornaam" autofocus></label>
   <button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen</button>
   <ul id="voornamen">
   </ul>
</body>
```

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for, please try with the below code. I have modified your code taken from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uq8k7h1o/).

```js
"use strict";

var valueMap = {};
document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function() {

  const voornaamInput = document.getElementById("voornaam");
  const voornaam = voornaamInput.value;

  let valToDisplay = "";
  if (valueMap[voornaam]) {
    valueMap[voornaam] = valueMap[voornaam] + 1;
    valToDisplay = `${voornaam} ${valueMap[voornaam]}`
  } else {
    valToDisplay = voornaam;
    valueMap[voornaam] = 1;
  }
  voornaamInput.value = "";
  voornaamInput.focus();
};


document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
 const ulElement = document.getElementById("voornamen");
  if(ulElement) {
   ulElement.innerHTML = '';
  }
  for (let key in valueMap) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = `${key} ${valueMap[key]}`;
    ulElement.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
    <label>Voornaam: <input id="voornaam" autofocus></label>
    <button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <ul id="voornamen">
    </ul>
```

Comment: This is kinda what I am trying to do. I am trying to basically input names till I press on a button ( stop for example) and then it outputs all the names and if a name has been entered multiple times --> Timothy: 5 for example :)

Comment: You meant, you also would like to display how many number of times a name has been entered?

Comment: Yes. So if someone types in the names Timothy, Pablo, Kamiel,.. It gives me those 3 names if I press on stop but if Timothy has been entered 4x it should say Timothy: 4. I have now gotten this with some help. All I am trying to do now is to make sure if I Type in 3 names and press stop and add another name it only keeps showing the actual updated UL and does not give me the old UL either. Here is the jsfiddle code --> https://jsfiddle.net/uq8k7h1o/

Comment: As per my understanding of what you are looking for, I have made changes in the code from JSFiddle link you shared. Try with the updated code in my answer and see whether this fulfils what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: No Problem. I’m glad to have helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map to store the input value as the **Key** and **count** as the value for the object.

JS Code

```
"use strict";

var valueMap = {}; // A global map to store the values
document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function() {

  const voornaamInput = document.getElementById("voornaam");
  const voornaam = voornaamInput.value;

  let valToDisplay = "";
  if (valueMap[voornaam]) {
    valueMap[voornaam] = valueMap[voornaam] + 1; // Increment if already present
    valToDisplay = `${voornaam} ${valueMap[voornaam]}`
  } else {
    valToDisplay = voornaam;
    valueMap[voornaam] = 1; // Make the new entry
  }
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = valToDisplay;
  document.getElementById("voornamen").appendChild(li);
  voornaamInput.value = "";
  voornaamInput.focus();
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway to wait with outputting list of names like that till after I press on a extra button to stop or?

Comment: I think we can achieve it by simply adding the value to our `valueMap` on click and then on stop we can print the `ul`.
Checkout this JSfiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/uq8k7h1o/

Comment: That looks perfect! I am now trying to change it so when I enter Pablo 2x and timothy 1x and then press stopp and add a name again it only shows the last updated UL. It seems to be showing everything including the first outputted UL.